# Why does my PixelShader ignore color but respond to alpha changes?

Tags: c++, shaders, hlsl, directx11, alpha-blending

I started teaching myself some DirectX a short time ago and found something I'm confused about. For some reason, I can only get the color of the model I'm drawing to vary between black and white, depending on the alpha that I set inside the shader.

This is my `PixelShader` (which compiles successfully during runtime):

```
float4 PS( VS_OUTPUT psInput ) : SV_Target
{
    return (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Given the components are `r,g,b,a` and I'm giving them `1,0,0,1`, this should return bright red! Instead, it produces this white area:

[image: mysteriously white area, instead of red]

I haven't set a blending state.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write:

```
return float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

The `float4` is necessary to construct a vector.  The way you've written it currently, the compiler is interpreting it as the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).  The result is that you only return the last element (the alpha component), which then gets replicated to all four components of the result.